# Order Legend Labels Across Instead of Down?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating a stacked horizontal bar chart. I can't seem to figure out how to order the legend so that blue is the top row and red is the bottom row while keeping the correct order in the bar chart. Here is my code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- structure(list(prop_count = structure(6:1, .Label = c("Comparison Fail", 
                                                             "Both Fail", "Bison Fail", 
                                                             "Slower", "Indeterminant", 
                                                             "Faster"), class = "factor"), 
                      n = c(58L, 129L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 1L), 
                      total = c(209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209), 
                      prop = c(0.277511961722488, 0.617224880382775, 
                               0.0382775119617225, 0.0191387559808612, 
                               0.0430622009569378, 0.00478468899521531), 
                      pct_text = c("27.8%", "61.7%", "3.8%", "1.9%", "4.3%", "0.5%"), 
                      plot_text = c("27.8% (58)", "61.7% (129)", "3.8% (8)", "1.9% (4)", "4.3% (9)", "0.5% (1)"), 
                      rolling_prop = c(0.277511961722488, 0.894736842105263, 
                                       0.933014354066986, 0.952153110047847, 0.995215311004785, 1), 
                      x_coord = c(0.138755980861244, 0.586124401913876, 0.913875598086124, 
                                  0.942583732057416, 0.973684210526316, 0.997607655502392)), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

dat
#> # A tibble: 6 x 8
#>   prop_count        n total    prop pct_text plot_text rolling_prop x_coord
#>   <fct>         <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>            <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 Faster           58   209 0.278   27.8%    27.8% (5…        0.278   0.139
#> 2 Indeterminant   129   209 0.617   61.7%    61.7% (1…        0.895   0.586
#> 3 Slower            8   209 0.0383  3.8%     3.8% (8)         0.933   0.914
#> 4 Bison Fail        4   209 0.0191  1.9%     1.9% (4)         0.952   0.943
#> 5 Both Fail         9   209 0.0431  4.3%     4.3% (9)         0.995   0.974
#> 6 Comparison F…     1   209 0.00478 0.5%     0.5% (1)         1       0.998

plot_prop_bar <- function(dat){
    run_colors <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 3, name = "Blues")
    failed_colors <- c("darkred", "red3", "red2")

    dat %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x = "1", y = prop, fill = prop_count)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_stack(),
                 width = .3) + 
        coord_flip() + 
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = c(failed_colors, run_colors)) + 
        guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + 
        labs(x = "Assessments", y = "Proportion (Count)") +
        theme(aspect.ratio = 1/3, 
              legend.position = "bottom",
              legend.title = element_blank(),
              axis.text.y = element_blank(),
              axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold", color= "grey25"), 
              axis.text = element_text(size = 13), 
              legend.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", color ="grey25"), 
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
}

plot_prop_bar(dat)
```

[image]

The desired output would be having the legend structured as so:

```
Faster Indeterminate Slower
Bison Fail Both Fail Comparison Fail
```